# Where all TimeZone times are maintained?

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

If we set `TimeZone` for a specific `Date`, how does java set time for that `Date`, like for example if we set `PST` as the time zone, how can it know the exact time zone, where is it being maintained??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The time zone data source is implementation-specific, but I believe most implementations use the [IANA database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) (aka zoneinfo, aka tz, aka Olson, aka TZDB).

Note that PST isn't really a time zone - it's "part" of a time zone. The time zone is "Pacific Time", usually specified with an ID of `"America/Los_Angeles"`.

Comment: Where does TZDB maintained actually and who maintains it? @Jon Skeet

Comment: @MaheshVarma: Did you follow the link? Everything is specified there.

Comment: I followed, but could you clarify this... "If we don't have the internet connection, then how does java figure out the timezone values?? @jon skeet"

Comment: A table with information about time zones is included in the Java runtime environment somewhere, you don't need an Internet connection.

Comment: @MaheshVarma: As Jesper says, the online version is just the data source - it's built into the JRE.

Comment: @JonSkeet What do you mean by "PST isn't really a time zone - it's "part" of a time zone" ?

Comment: @MaheshVarma: The time zone is Pacific Time, which varies between PST and PDT.