# Java locale/timezone list from JVM or OS?

Tags: java

May be a silly question, but recent project face a situation make me think about it.

I know JDK 6 and 5 has a little different type time zone code and locale they are able to support. But just curious about whether those code are totally defined in JVM or derived from the OS. From recent experience it seems OS dependent. So make this thread to confirm.

If the locale is OS dependent, then it is also OS sensitive, then I think when create String to Date conversion, if the application is going to deploy on different OS, so the locale and time zone OS-sensitivity must need to get concerned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the similar issue.
[TimeZone Information in JDk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789538/where-all-timezone-times-are-maintained)

They are integrated into the JRE. Not from the Operating System.

Locale is something that we set when we are installing our Operating System.

[Locale and Language Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318716%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you and seems it is a kind of popular question, dunno you have asked it two days ago...